# Why All 1's used as a second input in decrement operation of ALU?

Tags: digital-logic, microprocessor, vlsi, alu

Suppose the first four data inputs are X (X0, X1, X2, X3) and the second four data inputs are Y (Y0, Y1, Y2, Y3) in a 4-bit ALU. Why "All 1's" are used as an input for Y in the decrement operation of ALU?

Comment: Because X+0xf = X-1 for all X.

Answer (score 4):

Because all 1s is -1 in twos-complement encoding.

Think about it.  With a N-bit number, adding 2<sup>N</sup> doesn't change the value because the change is in the first bit past the number.  For example, consider adding 16 to a 4-bit number.  In binary that is:

```
    XXXX
 + 10000
 -------
   1XXXX
```

which is still just XXXX because by definition of a 4 bit number you only save the 4 bits.

So if adding 2<sup>N</sup> yields the same value, then adding 2<sup>N</sup>-1 will yield one less, which is the same as subtracting 1.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to understand this in decimal. Imagine that we're doing arithmetic on three-digit base 10 numbers: 445, 900, 132, 042, 007, etc. We can add the numbers together, but the result is always truncated to three digits. Here's an example:

> \$900 + 132 =  1032 \to 032\$

Now, look what happens when we add 999 to a number:

> \$042 + 999 = 1041 \to 041\$
>
> \$041 + 999 = 1040 \to 040\$
>
> \$040 + 999 = 1039 \to 039\$

As long as we drop the fourth digit, adding 999 (the largest possible three-digit number) works just like subtracting 1!

Binary works the same way. In your example, adding the largest possible four-bit number works just like subtracting 1. Again, this is because we're dropping the carry out from the high bit.

> \$0110 + 1111 = 10101 \to 0101\$
>
> \$0101 + 1111 = 10100 \to 0100\$
>
> \$0100 + 1111 = 10011 \to 0011\$
>
> \$0011 + 1111 = 10010 \to 0010\$

This is called *two's complement arithmetic*. Using this system, you can compute the "negative" of any n-bit binary number by subtracting it from \$2^n\$. For four-bit numbers, it works like this:

> \$-1 = 2^4 - 1 = 10000 - 0001 = 1111\$
>
> \$-5 = 2^4 - 5 = 10000 - 0101 = 1011\$

So adding 1011 to a four-bit number is just like subtracting 5, as long as you drop the last carry.

There's a faster and more common way to compute the two's complement -- invert all of the bits, then add one. This lets you compute a four-bit negative using inversion and addition, instead of needing five-bit subtraction. Here's how to compute -1 and -5 using this method:

> \$-1 = \lnot 0001 + 1 = 1110 + 1 = 1111\$
>
> \$-5 = \lnot 0101 + 1 = 1010 + 1 = 1011\$

Answer (score 0):

Think of the **subtraction between two numbers as adding the inverse of the second,
        x+(-y)** , so to decrement you add *-1*. 
 This expressed using the method of *[Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)* encoding, which states that: *To obtain the inverse of a  number you find its complement (replace 0 with 1 and vice versa) and then add 1 to the result*, leads to your question, in which: *1* in binary representation is: *0001*, its inverse element (i.e -1) is: 1111. 
 Check [Signed number representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) for further reading.